# How to place two square divs side by side covering the width of their parent

Tags: html, css

I want `.board` element to have a square aspect ratio. I want to show two of them side by side, together covering the width of their parent.
I don't want to use `width: 50%`, because I want to position `.wrap` element with `display: flex`.

```css
.board {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="board"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

When I do it like this, I get two divs with squashed width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `aspect-ratio` and `flex:1`

```css
.board {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  flex:1;
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="board"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively `flex:1` and `padding-bottom:50%;`

```css
.board {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="board"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```